# How do I format an int in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, formatting

So I have some big numbers in my database like 140800. How can I make it look like 140 800 to make it more readable ?

Comment: Numbers in a database don't have any format. Let your client application handle the formatting.

Comment: *"How can I make it look like 140 800 to make it more readable"* Don't; end of story. Handle any formatting in your presentation layer. `'140 800'` isn't a number, it's a string, and strings are **completely** different to numbers. For example `'10'` is **less than**  `'2'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can `convert/cast` the `integer` into `money` and use the `replace()` function as shown below:

*Note: manipulation based on this further may be tricky and need more attention to handle.*

```
SELECT Replace(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), try_cast(140800 as money), 1), '.00', ''),',', ' ')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the function [`format()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) with a long enough pattern like `'### ### ### ###'` which will cover the case up to 12 digit numbers, like this:

```
select ltrim(format(yournumber, '### ### ### ###'))
from tablename
```

Note that this way you get a `varchar` or `nvarchar` value and not a number.
See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c9d80ca4b8c93ece55cd89a2223ac174).